# Are open or closed sets locally closed?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, zariski-topology

I have two equivalent definitions of a locally closed subspace $X$:

1. $X$ is closed in its closure $\overline{X}$ with respect to the subspace toplogy.
2. $X$ is the intersection of an open and a closed set.

If $X$ is open, then $X\cap\overline{X} = X$, thus $X$ is the intersection of an open and a closed set, thus locally closed. If $X$ is closed, then $\overline{X} = X$, thus $X$ is closed in its closure.

My answer therefore tends to be yes, but I just want to make sure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that the first statement says $X$ closed in $\overline{X}$, not necessarily closed in the ambient topological space. So you cannot assume $X=\overline{X}$

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I don't understand. Suppose we have a topological space $A$ and $X\subseteq A$ is closed. Then we do have $X=\overline{X}$ right?

Comment: Wait. If $X$ is closed in its closure, then it is closed in the ambient space. You probably mean "open in its closure" ?

Comment: AH! Thank you, my bad, you are completely right. The definition seemed so useless liket this^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. Note that you can always write $X=X\cap Y$, where $Y$ is the underlying space, which is always open and closed in $Y$. So if $X$ is open (resp. closed), then it is the intersection of an open (resp. closed) set with a closed (resp. open) set.

The first definition should certainly read: *X is open in its closure*, since *closed in its closure* would imply that $X$ is closed.

By the way, here's an application of such sets:
$$\textit{ If $Y$ is a locally compact space and $X\subset Y$ is locally closed, then $X$ is locally compact as well.}$$

Comment: Oh right, so simple. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Stephan Hamcke Why if $X$ is closed in it's closure it means that $X$ is closed?

Comment: Oh, I see. Because if $X$ is closed in $\overline{X}$, this means that $X = \overline{X}\cap C$ where $C$ is some closed set in the topological space. So then $X$ is a closed set since it is the intersection of two closed spaces.