# Locally Closed Subset is Closed

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I have a question that arises from following former question of mine: [Question about Argument from Mumford's Red Book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208216/question-about-argument-from-mumfords-red-book)

There I wanted to find out under which conditions for a $k$-variety $X$ a certain locally closed set $Z \subset X \times_{Spek(k)}\ X$ is already closed.

The solution was (still not satisfying) that if we denote by

$$Cl := \{x \in X \times_{Spek(k)} X \vert x \text{ is a closed point in } X \times_{Spek(k)} X  \}$$ the set of closed points (which is dense) then $Z$ is closed in $X \times_{Spek(k)} X$ if the intersection $Z \cap Cl$ is closed in $Cl$ with respect to induced subset topology on $Cl$.

Now I have following QUESTION: Is is possible to verify this statement ***pure topologically***? So without any considerations on variety/scheme structure?

Or in other words: Does following statement hold and why?

Let $X$ be a topological space, $L \subset X$ a ***locally closed*** subset in $X$ and $D$ a ***dense*** subset.

Assume that $L \cap D $ is closed in $D$ wrt subset topology. Is then $L$ already closed in $X$? Why?

Remark: here I work with following definition(s) for locally closed: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+closed+set

Comment: What's really going on here is that you're using that for locally closed subsets of noetherian schemes, stable under specialization is equivalent to closed. There exists a purely topological version of this statement: for $X$ a noetherian sober topological space and $E\subset X$ a locally closed subset, $E$ is closed iff it's stable under specialization - see [tag 0542](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0542) for instance. Your statement is probably not true without these additional hypotheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> If $L\subset X$ is a locally closed subset in $X$ and $D$ a dense subset. If $L\cap D$ is closed in $D$ with respect to the subspace topology. Is then $L$ already closed?

No. Notice an open set is locally closed. (a proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161905/are-open-or-closed-sets-locally-closed) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736288/the-equivalency-of-two-definitions-of-locally-closed-sets)). Let $L=(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ and $D=\Bbb Q$. Then $L\cap D=(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)\cap \Bbb Q=[\sqrt2,\sqrt3]\cap \Bbb Q$, hence closed in $D$. But $(\sqrt2,\sqrt 3)$ is obviously not closed in $\Bbb R$.